# CdbCriteria BELONG_TO

Tags: activerecord, join, yii, cactivedataprovider

I have a model (**Inmueble**) with this relation:

```
'direccion' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Direccion', 'direccion_id_direccion'),
```

In this example:

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->addCondition('name = ' .$name,'AND');
$listInmueble=new CActiveDataProvider('Inmueble', 
                                         array('criteria' => $criteria,
                                               'pagination' => array('pageSize' => 10),
                                         ));
```

I accesing in the condition to the attribute **name** of the model Inmueble.

How can i do a CdbCriteria accesing the attributes of the relation, for example **where direccion.city = 'something'**?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
 $criteria->with = array(
    'direccion' => array(
    'condition' => 'direccion.city = :something',
    'params' => array(
     ':something' => 'someValue'
)
    )
    );
```